# How to do a toggle between multiple options with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've made an little design with circles that expand when clicking on them. I've multiple circles and want to be able to click and expand on one circle at a time and then the other circle closes.

Here's a codeply of my example:
https://www.codeply.com/p/7QdDsEF9ul

And here's the jQuery snippet:

```
$('.product1').click(function () {
$('#product1').toggleClass('expand');
$('.hidden#1').toggleClass('show');

$('.hidden#2').removeClass('show');
$('#product2').removeClass('expand');
});

$('.product2').click(function () {
$('#product2').toggleClass('expand');
$('.hidden#2').toggleClass('show');
});
```

As you can see this is not going to be very efficient, especially if I add more circles. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `div` that needs to be shown is a descendant of the `.circle` which has its class changed when shown, you can avoid having to fiddle with the child div by using the CSS rule `.expand div` instead. This way, changes to the parent with `.expand` will be sufficient.

Give all the `<a>`s a common class, maybe `product`, and on click, check to see if its child (the `.circle`) has the `expand` class or not. If it does, remove `.expand` from *all* elements - otherwise, remove `expand` from all elements *but then* add it to the `.circle` child:

```js
$('.product').click(function() {
  const $circle = $(this).children();
  if ($circle.hasClass('expand')) {
    $('.expand').removeClass('expand');
  } else {
    $('.expand').removeClass('expand');
    $circle.addClass('expand');
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  font-size: 2.25em;
}

.active {
  color: #6bd627;
}

.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #00aae8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.expand {
  height: 248px !important;
  background-color: #6bd627 !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.expand div {
  display: block !important;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.link {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  color: #000;
}

ul,
ol {
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: -0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid s1">
  <div class="container py-5">
    <div class="row py-5 align-items-end">

      <div class="col-sm text-center">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" class="pb-3 img-fluid" />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-0 product">
          <div class="circle">
            <h2>Title 1</h2>
            <div class="hidden"><br>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="list-item"><span class="link">Top Picks</span></li>
                <li class="list-item"><span class="link">By Brand</span></li>
                <li class="list-item"><span class="link">By Price</span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm text-center">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" class="pb-3 img-fluid" />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-0 product">
          <div class="circle">
            <h2>Title 1</h2>
            <div class="hidden" id="2"><br>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="list-item"><span class="link">Top Picks</span></li>
                <li class="list-item"><span class="link">By Brand</span></li>
                <li class="list-item"><span class="link">By Price</span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm text-center">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" class="pb-3 img-fluid" />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-0 product">
          <div class="circle">
            <h2>Title 1</h2>
            <div class="hidden"><br>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="list-item"><span class="link">Top Picks</span></li>
                <li class="list-item"><span class="link">By Brand</span></li>
                <li class="list-item"><span class="link">By Price</span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You don't need any IDs or numeric-indexed classes now.

Comment: Perfect, that worked! And thanks for the detailed info. This way the code is way cleaner and stays smaller

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `id` and just use the class `.product`, then itereate through all

```
$('.product').each(function(i,v){
    console.log({i:i,v:v,'$(this)':$(this)});
    $(this).on('click',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('expand');
        $(this).find('.hidden').toggleClass('show');
    })
});
```

In your current html, this is what you said product DOM looks like:

```
  <div class="col-sm text-center">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" class="pb-3 img-fluid" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-0 product2">
      <div class="circle" id="product1">
        <h2>Title 1</h2>
        <div class="hidden" id="2"><br>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="list-item"><span class="link">Top Picks</span></li>
            <li class="list-item"><span class="link">By Brand</span></li>
            <li class="list-item"><span class="link">By Price</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

By changing just this line:

```
      <div class="circle" id="product1">
```

to:

```
      <div class="circle product">
```

you can iterate through all and toggle classes for itself and its child `'.hidden'`

The `$(this)` keyword has special meaning inside callback functions like `.each()`, however i also left in the `function(i,v)` which means `function(index,value)` so you can even use those, as i showed via console.

**Showing only one product circle at a time**

I left everything as the simple `toggleClass()` that you shared above, though if you wanted to be more explicit you can use `hasClass()` checks, and can also have only one visible product circle at all times by adding this to first line of the click handler:

`$('.product.expand').removeClass('expand').find('.hidden').removeClass('show');`

**Working Snippet/Fiddle**

Codeply needs you to create account and doesnt include code inside post in case service goes down in future, so i moved this inside a stackoverflow snippet so you can see working code.

```js
$('.product').each(function(i,v){
        // console.log({i:i,v:v,'$(this)':$(this)});
        $(this).on('click',function(){ 
            // $('.product.expand').removeClass('expand').find('.hidden').removeClass('show');
            $(this).toggleClass('expand');
            $(this).find('.hidden').toggleClass('show');
        })
    });

    // $('.product1').click(function() {
    //   $(this).nextAll('.hidden:first').toggleClass('show');
    // });
```

```css
a {
  font-size: 2.25em;
}
 .active {
  color: #6bd627;
}
 .circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #00aae8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
}
 .circle h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 55px;
}
 .expand {
  height: 248px !important;
  background-color: #6bd627 !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
}
 .hidden {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
 .show {
  display: block !important;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
 .link {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  color: #000;
}
 ul, ol {
  margin: 0;
}
 li {
  margin-bottom: -0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid s1" style="margin-bottom:400px;">
    <div class="container py-5">
    <div class="row py-5 align-items-end">
        
      <div class="col-sm text-center">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" class="pb-3 img-fluid" />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-0 product1">
          <div class="circle product">
            <h2>Title 1</h2>
            <div class="hidden" id="1"><br>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="list-item"><span class="link">Top Picks</span></li>
            <li class="list-item"><span class="link">By Brand</span></li>
          <li class="list-item"><span class="link">By Price</span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm text-center">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" class="pb-3 img-fluid" />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-0 product2">
          <div class="circle product">
            <h2>Title 1</h2>
            <div class="hidden" id="2"><br>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="list-item"><span class="link">Top Picks</span></li>
            <li class="list-item"><span class="link">By Brand</span></li>
          <li class="list-item"><span class="link">By Price</span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm text-center">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" class="pb-3 img-fluid" />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-0 product1">
          <div class="circle product">
            <h2>Title 1</h2>
            <div class="hidden"><br>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="list-item"><span class="link">Top Picks</span></li>
            <li class="list-item"><span class="link">By Brand</span></li>
          <li class="list-item"><span class="link">By Price</span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```